# AngularJS: Only post non-blank values

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I am trying to $http.post a JSON object from a form. I can't seem to find the right syntax. Let's assume my form only takes one value (name). I use ng-model to bind the name to an object called modcampaign.name.

What's the correct syntax to post this to a http service?
Further, what if I had another input box, **Description**, and only want to bind this to modcampaign.description **if the user entered data in the input box?** If the input box is empty, I'd like to take the value for .description from another object (like modcampaign2.description).

```
<form ng-submit="modifyCampaign(selCampaign, newName)" class="form-horizontal" name="modCampaign">
            <!-- Modify Name -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="modName">Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="modName" ng-model="modCampaign.name"/>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

This is the script file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('js/campaigns.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.campaigns = data;
    });

    $http.post('js/campaign_mod.json').success(function (data) {
        data = $scope.modCampaign;
    });

    $scope.selCampaign={};
    $scope.selectCampaign = function (campaign) {
        $scope.toggleCampaign = !$scope.toggleCampaign;
        $scope.selCampaign = campaign;
    };

    $scope.abbrechen = function () {
        $scope.toggleCampaign = !$scope.toggleCampaign;
    };

    $scope.submit = function () {
        $http.post('')
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Is it possible to see your angular controller and service files?

Comment: I was experimenting with $http.post a little bit as you can see. only the $http.get works though.

Comment: You can check out my answer below with a codepen link, depending on the way your back end is structured sending and Object like so **{ name: modCampaign.name, description: modCampaign.description }** you can extract the value with the property name after sending with $http POST verb

Comment: I think you should check out this link also https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Answer (score 0):

You can include something like this in your controller:

```
   $scope.modCampaign = {};

   //this gets called on ng-submit
   $scope.submitData = function(){

       $http.post("api-end-point", $scope.modCompaign).success(function(data, status) {
            //handle response etc.
       });

   }
```

Your html will have something like this:

```
<form ng-submit="submitData()" class="form-horizontal" name="modCampaign">
        <!-- Modify Name -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="modName">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="modName" ng-model="modCampaign.name"/>
               <textarea ng-model="modCampaign.description"/></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JSON.stringify()`

example

```
$http({
 method: "POST",
 url: 'http://www.example.com/posturl',
 data : JSON.stringify($scope.modcampaign)
}).success(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    // write any action after post success
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form ng-submit="modifyCampaign(modCampaign)" class="form-horizontal" name="modCampaign">
        <!-- Modify Name -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="modName">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="modName" ng-model="modCampaign.name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="modDescription">Description</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="modDescription" ng-model="modCampaign.description"/>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.modifyCampaign = function(modCampaign) {
  console.log(modCampaign) 
  alert(modCampaign.name) // name:"jane"
  alert(modCampaign.description) // description: "hello"
  $http.post('js/campaign_mod.json', { name: modCampaign.name, description: modCampaign.description }).success(function (data) {
   console.log(data)
  });
 }
}]);
```

This method lets you bind all the form value to one object and then you can decode the value in your controller file, below is a link to a working example
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjYLvg